# How to Unistall application installed using WINEHQ?

Tags: wine, adobe-acrobat

I tried installing `Acrobat Reader 9` (quite old version) using `wine`. It seemed it had issues installing the application. `Wine` did create installation folders in the `Program Files 86`. `Reader` is showing up in the open with application options.
[image: I am thinking ADOB-DWN is the adobe reader app]
In above screenshot - I am thinking `ADOB-DWN` is the adobe reader app
On opening with this app, i get below error.
[image]

I am not sure if this error can be fixed or not (please feel free to comment). But irrespectively I want to uninstall acrobat reader.
**So does what uninstallating an application installed with Wine take.** Is it just deleting the Adobe folder from program file (in this case I don't think `ADOB-DWN` will  be removed from "Open with Application" context. ) or is there a defined process to uninstall application using wine etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
wine uninstaller
```

Wine will open the “Add/Remove Programs” control panel applet. Select the application you want to uninstall and click on the “Remove” button.